# can't get data-id from <td> onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code creating a td

```
html += "<td data-id='test' class='journal' style='max-width:200px;'>"+record.source_account_code+"</td>";
```

and then the following code

```
    $(document).on('click', '#table-content td', e => {
   console.log("td onclick called")
   console.log($(this).attr('data-id'))
});
```

which executes correctly but instead of outputting "test" I get "undefined"

I have tried doing it this way as well

```
$(this).data("id")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a regular function, not an arrow function:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#table-content td', function() {
  console.log("td onclick called")
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'))
});


document.querySelector('#table-content').innerHTML += "<td data-id='test' class='journal' style='max-width:200px;'>record</td>";
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table-content"></table>
```

This is because jQuery will bind the event target to the function, which is why `this` will refer to the element. You can't bind to an arrow function however. It's an ES6 quirk.

Comment: For OP, there is more reading [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-interchangeable/34361380#34361380)